# \overleftarrow in subfigure caption

Tags: math-mode, subfloats

This compiles fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

test: $\overleftarrow{a}$

\begin{figure}
    %\subfloat[Subcaption $\overleftarrow{a}$]{\framebox[3cm]{First}}
    \subfloat[Subcaption $b$]{\framebox[3cm]{Second}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I put a Math-Mode in the caption of the subfloat. In the next example I put math mode and \overleftarrow, and although it gives the right output, it produces an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

test: $\overleftarrow{a}$

\begin{figure}
    \subfloat[Subcaption $\overleftarrow{a}$]{\framebox[3cm]{First}} \hfill
    \subfloat[Subcaption $b$]{\framebox[3cm]{Second}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Illegal parameter number in definition of \sf@captionlist.
--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
               \crcr 
l.10 ...\overleftarrow{a}$]{\framebox[3cm]{First}}
```

Why is there an error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `\protect`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

test: $\overleftarrow{a}$

\begin{figure}
    \subfloat[Subcaption $\protect\overleftarrow{a}$]{\framebox[3cm]{First}} \hfill
    \subfloat[Subcaption $b$]{\framebox[3cm]{Second}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/15925) for detailed discussion of why this is necessary.

Comment: @AndrewSwann --- thanks; I was just looking for a decent reference on this so as to add a link.