# Error: Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a

Tags: tables, errors, captions

When I am using `\caption{$\E_\A(D)$ where $\ora{UF}\!_n$}` inside a table environment there shows some errors.

Error :

```
Only one # is allowed per tab. ...crcr }}}_n$\relax }}{95}{table.caption.41}
```

Error :

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a. \caption{$\E_\A(D)$ where $\ora{UF}\!_n$}
```

Here `\E` stands for `\mathscr{E}`, `\A` stands for `\text{\k{A}}`, `\ora` for `\overrightarrow`.

Please help resolving this problem.

Comment: I think defining new commands of only one letter is a bad idea. However, please add a complete MWE (since you're member for more than one year you should know it's necessary).

Comment: This problem is similar in nature to [`\overleftarrow` in subfigure caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67400/5764). Different environment, but it's the same cause and therefore a similar solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\overrightarrow` is not robust and breaks in moving arguments. Protect it with `\protect`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*{\A}{\text{\k{A}}}
\newcommand*{\E}{\mathscr{E}}
\newcommand*{\ora}{\overrightarrow}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\caption{$\E_\A(D)$ where $\protect\ora{UF}\!_n$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Alternative:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\ora}{\overrightarrow}
```

Then `\ora` is robust and `\protect` is not needed.