# Glossary entries error

Tags: symbols, glossaries

I'm trying to introduce some entries in the glossary with \usepackage{glossaries} and I don't know how to introduce symbols with arrows, like vector fields. If I don't use name=$\overrightarrow{E}$, works fine but I need to put the right symbol.

this is my entry:

```
\newglossaryentry{symb:efield}{
name=$\overrightarrow{E}$,
description={Electric Field},
sort=symbolefield, type=symbolslist
}
```

and I have at least 4 error related to that:

- Illegal parameter number in definition of \glo@symb:efield@text.
- Illegal parameter number in definition of \glo@symb:efield@plural.
- Illegal parameter number in definition of \glo@symb:efield@first.
- Illegal parameter number in definition of \glo@symb:efield@firstpl.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossary*{symbolslist}{Symbols list}

\newcommand{\field}[1]{\protect\overrightarrow{#1}}  % use \protect 

\newglossaryentry{symb:efield}{%
    type=symbolslist,
    name={\ensuremath{\field{E}}},
    description={Electric Field},
    sort=symbolefield, 
}
    
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}    

overrightarrow: $\field{AB}$

\medskip

 \gls{symb:efield}   
  
\printglossary[type=symbolslist]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: A]

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387939/161015

Must use use `\protect` because  `overrightarrow` is not robust.

Or use  `\DeclareRobustCommand{\field}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}`  as alternative.

Comment: Thank you! It works!